# complex With query on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion, with-statement

Could you please explain what do these lines of code do?

**Table 1: INT,VARCHAR,FLOAT**

```
ID Name  value
---------------------------
1   a1  32116580
2   a2  50785384
3   a3  54327508
4   a4  61030844

;with coords(i,row,col,total,N) as (
select 1,1,1,N.N*(N.N+1)/2, N.N
from (select count(*) N from table1) N
union all
select i+1,
       case when col+1>N then row+1 else row end,
       case when col+1>N then row+1 else col+1 end,
       total, N
from coords
where i<total
)
```

I know `with` provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger query, so it is like if I declare some variables I would use, but after that I am a little confused...And Why the use of `case` for getting `row and col`; Also why in the case there are two:  `case when col+1>N then row+1 else` , How does SQL know `when to do one case or the other`?...

```
i  row col total N
--------------------
1   1   1   10   4
2   1   2   10   4
3   1   3   10   4
4   1   4   10   4
5   2   2   10   4
6   2   3   10   4
7   2   4   10   4
8   3   3   10   4
9   3   4   10   4
10  4   4   10   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of table1 can be ignored since only the count is being used - thus you can rewrite your CTE as:

```
;with coords(i,row,col,total,N) as (
    select 1, 1, 1, 10, 4
    union all
    select i+1,
           case when col+1>N then row+1 else row end,
           case when col+1>N then row+1 else col+1 end,
           total, N
    from coords
    where i<total
    )
SELECT * FROM coords
```

...with a `SELECT * FROM coords` there to visualise the results.

The `select 1, 1, 1, 10, 4` 'seeds' the recursion - this is the row from which later levels of the recursion will derive.  The rest of the rows are built up from the second query acting upon (initially) the seed row and then the resultant row from the second query fed back in to itself etc.

Comment: could you explain the case statements, why to have `when col+1>N then row+1` why else `row`, and why else `col+1`

Comment: Run the query and take a look at the output.  the ith row is the ith level of recursion - with the first row being the 'seed row'.  You can see the effect the CASEs have by working out how row (n + 1) was derived from row n.

Comment: My pleasure.  I'd recommend avoiding using recursive CTEs unless you've a good use for them, mind.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is creating a [`common table expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

It is basically create a temporary table structure from the `select` query within. The select statement is doing the following:

1) Selecting a bunch of default values `1,1,1` and a calculation `N.N*(N.N+1)/2` and finally a value from the `N` table `N.N`
2) `UNION`ing in another `select` statement.
3) The second select is doing some conditional output with the case statements.

Comment: As I can see, it is like putting that table into a matrix, Am I right?

Comment: Correct. martix would not be the correct term for SQL server. Analogous to a temp table or table variable.

Comment: so when you put a lot of `1,1,1` is like getting the sum of all elements in the table right?, also the var `i` is it used to know in which column and row are we?, and, in your 2)`UNION` ing in another `SELECT` Why is that?